# Putting a Presta stem nut inside the rim?

Tags: innertube, rims, presta

Has anyone ever heard of this? I'm not sure how it happened, but when I went to replace my tire today, I found that I had two stem lock nuts on my valve. One inside the rim and one in the normal place. Not sure if the shop did this for me a awhile back or if I did this absentmindedly last time I changed it. Anyway, it didn't cause any problems and I put at least a few hundred miles on it like that.

Any reason to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Does your rim have a 6mm Presta sized hole, or a 8mm Schrader sized hole?  Could be the first nut on was in lieu of a grommit ?

Comment: Yeah, the usual reason for that is a hole that's too big for a presta tube and using the nut to take up some space.

Comment: nope. Rim has the proper presta hole...

Comment: Then assume whoever installed it was drunk.

Comment: Assuming the rim is drilled for Presta, there is no reason to do this, and doing it could potentially lead to premature tube failure.

Answer (score 6):

It is a commonly used quick and dirty fix when you don't have a purpose-built grommet to install in a rim cut for a Schrader valve. It may also not be a terrible idea if, for whatever reason, your Presta-hole rim has a burr or sharp edge and you want to avoid any possibility of problems with that.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no reason for that type of installation unless the whole in the rim is sized for a Schrader valve, rather than a presta valve.

It is, as you found, unlikely to cause an issue though.

Answer (score 1):

I put one inside and outside after having a few failures of the valve stem tube connection point. It appeared that the stem was being pulled away from the tube
Now months of use later no issues